# How can I play a Lottie on Scroll in a React app?

Tags: reactjs, lottie

Lottiefiles has a lottie interactive guide where they show how everything works but despite trying a bunch of stuff I can't get it to work on react. This is what I have so far.
This is the lottie interactive page: https://lottiefiles.com/interactivity

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import "@lottiefiles/lottie-player";
import { create } from "@lottiefiles/lottie-interactivity";
import Lottie from "react-lottie";


export default function App() {
  const lottiee = React.useRef(null);
  
    }
  };
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (event) {
    //do work

    React.useEffect(() => {
      lottiee.current.addEventListener("load", function (e) {
        create({
          mode: "scroll",
          player: "#firstLottie",
          actions: [
            {
              visibility: [0, 1],
              type: "seek",
              frames: [0, 300]
            }
          ]
        });
      });
    }, []);
  });
  return (
    <div className="App">
    
      <lottie-player
        ref={lottiee} // 2. set the reference for the player
        id="firstLottie"
        controls
        mode="scroll"
        src="https://assets3.lottiefiles.com/packages/lf20_UJNc2t.json"
        style={{ width: "320px" }}
      ></lottie-player>
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Few things to note.

1 - import the Lottie player as

```
import * as LottiePlayer from "@lottiefiles/lottie-player";
```

2 - remove the document ready listener and instead add the ref variable to the useEffect arguements (this way the method inside it runs only when lottiee variable is not null)

3 - change the frame number in frames array to total frames of your Lottie.

Working example provided below

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import * as LottiePlayer from "@lottiefiles/lottie-player";
import { create } from "@lottiefiles/lottie-interactivity";

export default function App() {
  const lottiee = React.useRef(null);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    lottiee.current.addEventListener("load", function (e) {
      create({
        mode: "scroll",
        player: "#firstLottie",
        actions: [
          {
            visibility: [0, 1],
            type: "seek",
            frames: [0, 181]
          }
        ]
      });
    });
  }, [lottiee]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div style={{ height: "400px" }}></div>
      <lottie-player
        ref={lottiee} // 2. set the reference for the player
        id="firstLottie"
        controls
        mode="scroll"
        src="https://assets6.lottiefiles.com/packages/lf20_ru7ffwai.json"
        style={{ width: "320px" }}
      ></lottie-player>
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Hey thank you for helping! I tested your code but it only shows a blank page. It's not working for me really.

Comment: could you post up the code with the new changes